# Making Sum result As Distinct In mysql?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Here is my code

```
 select count(  model.voter.voterId),  


 SUM( CASE WHEN model.voter.age BETWEEN  :AGE18 and :AGE25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ageCount ,  
 SUM( CASE WHEN model.voter.age BETWEEN  :AGE26 and :AGE35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ageCount ,  
 SUM( CASE WHEN model.voter.age BETWEEN  :AGE36 and :AGE45 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ageCount ,  
 SUM( CASE WHEN model.voter.age BETWEEN  :AGE46 and :AGE60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ageCount , 
 SUM( CASE WHEN model.voter.age > :AGE60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ageC  from User model  where  model.voter.voterId in(:voterIds)
```

i passed 21 objects but it showing 22 the result also for 22 only
 when i make  `select count( distict  model.voter.voterId)` it 21 but toal result still 22

can  i make sum condition as distinct? how?

```
select count(uservoterd0_.voter_id) as col_0_0_, SUM(case when voter1_.age between 18 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as col_1_0_, SUM(case when voter1_.age between 26 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as col_2_0_, SUM(case when voter1_.age between 36 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as col_3_0_, SUM(case when voter1_.age between 46 and 60 then 1 else 0 end) as col_4_0_, SUM(case when voter1_.age>60 then 1 else 0 end) as col_5_0_ from user_voter_details uservoterd0_ inner join voter voter1_ on uservoterd0_.voter_id=voter1_.voter_id where uservoterd0_.voter_id in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)
```

Comment: ":AGE18" I'm not familiar with this syntax. What is it?

Comment: assume 18 as input parameter

Comment: OK, so can we see the actual query that's passed to MySQL? And giving every column the same name - doesn't that cause confusion?

Comment: eventhough  i changed that one ni use

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. So this *isn't* your code!?!

Comment: yes it is,above above  hibernate that generate sql and that goes to db

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Without seeing an echo of the actual query I cannot tell you why it might be wrong, but perhaps others can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in 21 user ids but getting the value of 22 from your `count()`, then you have duplicate rows in your data.

Try running this query to see where the duplicates are:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(voterId ), max(voterId)
from (select voterId, count(*) as cnt
      from user u
      group by voterId
     ) t
group by cnt
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: @AnilHoney . . . Multiple rows with the same `voterId` in the `user` table.